# Converting datasnaphot from firebase to List<Array> - Xamarin.Droid

Tags: c#, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android

I just started using firebase today. I am trying pass my dummy data in the firebase to a List. Using snapshot, I fetch my data into a variable called fetched data and pass my data to the List. But then, I cast the snapshot to DataContent. I get the specified cast not valid. Why is my cast not working, Firebase has a unique way of casting?

Here is a little part of my code

```
  List<DataContent>DisplayData = new List <DataContent>();

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.myView);

            firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseUrl);

            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.Instance;
            mLike = FirebaseDatabase.Instance.Reference.Child("Table");

            mDatabase.AddValueEventListener(this);
            mDatabase.KeepSynced(true);




        public void OnCancelled(DatabaseError error)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public  void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
             var fireBaseData = snapshot.Child(postBlogKeyId);

              DisplayData.Add((DataContent)fireBaseData);

        }
```

Comment: I would probably want it in Xamarin as it is sometimes worrisome for me converting the java logic into xamarin

Answer (score 0):

> I get the specified cast not valid. Why is my cast not working, Firebase has a unique way of casting?

First, Please make sure it is an object, not a list under `snapshot.Child(postBlogKeyId)`.

Second, by `snapshot.Child(postBlogKeyId)`, you get an `DataSnapShot` object, which is a wrapper of your data content, you need to use `snapshot.Child(postBlogKeyId).Value` to get the data content.

If it still doesn't work, please debug `snapshot.ToString()` and post the result of that.